# Custom analyzer for RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, analyzer

I need some info on developing a custom analyzer for RavenDB.
I'm in the stage of setting up the DLL, the custom analyzer will be pretty simple as I need just a small modification of the StandardAnalyzer.

I found this page:
http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/05/alphanumeric-lucene-analyzer-for-ravendb.html

Obviously it doesn't work out of the box :-)

1) Where do I have to put the custom analyzer DLL? In my hard disk the path of Raven.Database.dll is "D:\ravendb\Server", so I put the Raven.Extensions.AlphanumericAnalyzer.dll of the example above in the new folder "D:\ravendb\Server\Analyzers".

2) Ho can I check if the DLL is recognized and loaded by RavenDB server (after the service has been reloaded)?

3) How can I reference the new analyzer at the bottom of index page settings of web GUI of RavenDB? I read about fully qualified type name, using IlSpy I found something like "Raven.Extensions.AlphanumericAnalyzer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

4) Should the solution be compiled in x85 or AnyCPU? Debug or Release?

5) The link talks about a custom analyzer for RavenDB 2.5, any difference with RavenDB 3.5?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1) That seems to be the right path, given the default config.

2) Create an index that uses that analyzer. If it works, it was loaded.

3) The easiest way to get the right value is to call `typeof(YourAnalyze).AssemblyQualifiedName`

4) AnyCPU, Release

5) Not for your needs, it should be the same.